# How to copy text to clipboard from different buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, web, copy, clipboard

I am trying to create a web element that copies a promo code to the clipboard when a button is pressed. I have successfully done this for one button but when others are added it only ever copies the code from the first button. I think that this is because they share an ID.

Here are what my buttons look like in HTML:
(All of them have a different code in the "contentPromo" p tag, that text is what I am trying to copy to clipboard)

```
<!-- Button 1 -->
<div class="accordionPromo">
    <button id="copy">Get A Code</button>
</div>

<div class="panel">
<p id="contentPromo">Reds15</p>
</div>




<!-- Button 2 -->
<div class="accordionPromo">
    <button id="copy">Get A Code</button>
</div>

<div class="panel">
<p id="contentPromo">Cub50</p>
</div>
```

(I have 2 other buttons like this)

I was hoping that each button could be clicked its promo code would copy to clipboard. As of right now if I click on the first button it will copy Reds15. When I click on the second button it doesn't copy anything and my clipboard is unchanged. Here is my JavaScript that controls the copy to clipboard:

```
// Reference of the paragraph tag
const contentPromo = document.getElementById("contentPromo");


// Reference of the copy button
const copyBtn = document.getElementById("copy");

// Copy button's onclick handler
copyBtn.onclick = copyToClipboard;


// Method responsible for copying the contentPromo
function copyToClipboard() {
    navigator.clipboard
       .writeText(contentPromo.innerText)
       .then(() => alert("Copied to clipboard"))
       .catch((e) => alert(e.message));
}
```

How do I get this to work for 4 separate buttons?

Comment: I do not have an answer right now, and my thoughts are not clear about this ... so only commenting ... if you have 4 identical objects, then you have to refer to them by starting at the parent container and referring to them by object number inside the parent container

Comment: *I think that this is because they share an ID* - this is an illegal html, ids should be unique

Answer (score 0):

One of the big things is you have multiple items with the same ID which isn't a good thing in HTML. They are supposed to all be unique so the code is finding the first one and giving you that data.

A suggestion might be to simplify things. If you don't need a visual (the panel class divs) give each button a unique ID that is the code you want to use.

A quick example...

```
<style>
    .accordionPromo {
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }   
</style>

<!-- Button 1 -->
<div class="accordionPromo">
    <button id="Reds15">Get A Code</button>
</div>

<!-- Button 2 -->
<div class="accordionPromo">
    <button id="Cub50">Get A Code</button>
</div>

<script>
    var clickedButton;
    //vanilla Javascript
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(obj) {
      obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
        copyToClipboard(this.id);
      });
    });

    //jQuery option
    /*
    $('button').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
        copyToClipboard(this.id);
        });
    });
    */

    function copyToClipboard(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
        navigator.clipboard
            .writeText(txt)
            .then(() => console.log('Copied to clipboard'))
            .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    }
</script>
```

The querySelectorAll will get all elements on the page with class, type, etc. In this case 'button' then adding a listener when it's clicked. You can still have the panel divs as a visual and styling but the heavy lifting is in the button itself and the event listener. Adding a jQuery option too, just remove the one you don't need.

-Edit: changed - added copy to clipboard better matching the OP question

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This looks like a good way to handle 4 buttons. I'm still newer to HTML and Javascript so you helped me out a lot thanks!